# How can one user be faster than the other?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, user-account

On our 10.6.8 Mac Mini Late 2009 Edition, we have 4 users, 3 of which are in regular use. One is mine, let's call it 'a'. The second one is someone else's, let's call it 'b'. The third one we both use, let's call it 'c'. a and c have administrator rights. The unused is the owner.

So, the 'a' account is kind of slow sometimes, but it's what you'd expect after almost 5 years of usage. But here's the deal. 'b' and 'c' often behave *much* slower than that (takes 2-5 minutes to complete login). Sometimes they're as fast as 'a', but that's seldom.

So yeah, whaddya think about this? Why does this happen? And if you know why, how can I fix it?

Comment: You might need to provide more information about the slowness… apps starting? Space left on the HDD? What happens with a hypothetical user "D" (new)? etc.

Comment: Login items and number of apps to restart heavily influence login time as well

Comment: Are the users loggig in at the same time ie fast user switching or are they the only one on the Mac at the same time?

Comment: @patrix 'a' actually has _more_ login items than the slower one.

Comment: @MartínMarconcini Safari takes 2-5 minutes to start on 'c'. 30GB left on HDD. Plus, we have the owner of the computer account, 'd', whose owner is not living in our house anymore, and no-one else knows the password. I can say that 'd' was quite fast, as it was never used.

Comment: @Mark fast user switching

Comment: With fast user switching the apps in the starting user keep running and the memory they take so it is to be expected starting the second user would be slower than if they started as the first login - what are the times when they are both the first?

Comment: @Mark I'll have to try that—I just realized it may be the sometimes notorious amount of _Flash_ videos open on 'a'.

Answer (score 1):

Check your login items. Have a look in System Preferences->Users & Groups->Login Items, and delete anything you don't need starting at login. Also try cleaning up your Desktop, so the computer doesn't have to load all those little tiny images when it's busy trying to do other things. Also check if there are any launch agents running at login. (Look in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` for launch agents specific to your user. To find this folder, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>, and enter the above path.) You'll see things like `com.skype.c2c_service.plist`. You should be able to work out whether they belong to apps that you want starting at login. (If not, delete the files.)

Comment: 'a' actually has _more_ login tiems than 'c'. I'll see what I can do. Let's see if your answer is accepted. You'll see in the coming weeks, as I am quite prone to procrastination.

Comment: Are there any login items that are exclusive to b and c? If a's fast, and there's a login item that a doesn't have, but the other two do have, I would start to get suspicious...

Comment: No, there aren't any exclusive login items on b or c.